# analogRead returning 0 constantly when connected to joystick

Tags: analogread, wires, joystick

What reasons could there be for a joystick to return 0 when using analogRead?

X-pin is connected to AO and y-pin is connected to A1.

VCC is connected to 5V and GRND is connected to GRND.

By default (as in when not using the joystick) the value should be approximately 500, right? Well why is the value then 0? Can this only be a wiring issue?

Comment: What value do you get when you move the stick? Maybe 0 just means centre and then when the stick is moved you get -90 and +90 (or something like that)?

Comment: It doesn't go below 0 at any point, however it does increase by 2 or so when moved up/right

Comment: Moving just 2 sounds like electrical static and that the joystick is not working or not powered correctly. Have you set your arduino analog pins as INPUT?

Comment: thank you... I changed the wiring a bit and it worked :)

Comment: For a question like this you need to a) check your joystick out of circuit with an ohm meter and confirm the values that the pots are producing, and b) describe (ideally with a schematic) the exact circuit you're using. Note that as it stands this isn't a very good StackExchange question because it's unlikely to help anybody else. Going back and filling in the details might get you some upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to identify the problem.

1. Disconnect A0/A1 from Arduino and use a multimeter to check the voltage coming from the joystick X and Y. If it swings from 0 to 5V....the problem is in the Arduino. Check your code and connections. Maybe your wires are damaged?
2. If the voltage is not changing at X and Y pins, disconnect power from the joystick and use a multimeter to check the joystick potentiometer. Check all three terminals in each axis of the joystick. If R is the measured resistance between the two outer pins, then the resistance between the central pin and each of the outer pins should vary from 0 to R depending on the position of the joystick.
3. If there is no problem at all with the joystick readings by potentiometer then the problem has to be on the Arduino side.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer after clarification:-

Moving the joystick also failed to produce a valid reading which indicated a wiring issue or incorrect configuration of the Analog `pin` in the Arduino code.

Proven to be a wiring problem